Walking animation breaks in unity 3D character
I have a problem that I did not managed to solved for about two days now. I made a simple third person character controller for the (W, S, A, D) keys using a character from mixamo, the problem is that when I pressing any of those keys the animation starts playing, stops and returns to the idle pose for a split second and then comeback and stays for somewhere aroung one second after the player stoped moving.The way I am setting the animation is that I made an animator controller that looks like this
I set (Loop Time, diabled hash exit, applied humanoid, set triggers)

Does anyone knows what could go wrong here?
What is the write way to set animations in unity anyway?
The PlayerController.cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float moveSpeed = 5f;

    [SerializeField] float rotationSpeed = 1000f;
    [SerializeField] Animator animator;

    Quaternion targetRotation;
    
    CameraController cameraController;

    private void Awake() {
        cameraController = Camera.main.GetComponent<CameraController>();
    }

    private void Update() {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float vartical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        float moveAmount = Mathf.Clamp01(Mathf.Abs(horizontal) + Mathf.Abs(vartical));

        var moveInput = new Vector3(horizontal, 0, vartical).normalized;
        var moveDirection = cameraController.PlanerRotation * moveInput;

        if (moveAmount > 0) {
            animator.SetTrigger("JogForward"); // Player is moving setting jog animation
            transform.position += moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime * moveDirection;
            targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(moveDirection);
        } else {
            // player stoped moving setting idle pose
            animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
        }
        

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation,
            rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}

structure:
player (game object) (playerController.cs attached here)

maximo character (animator attached here)


you say it stops, it will depend on your settings, and how you have configured the transitions..  In part it looks because you trigger a single play of the animator, rather than  rely on some form of velocity or movement, therefore it has been told to play it once and go back to idle, so it does.

how can I set the animation where the players move in the space reliably?

have a value perameter, even if its just a simple int for yes(1), no(0), then, you set the value to 0 and have if <1 transition out, if >0 transition in, and you will remain running/walkikng/flying whatever the animation is until that value changes outside the range, triggers are more a jump, or, punch...
